# $.toString() at google keywords says [native code]

Tags: javascript, firebug, tostring, native-code

I always thought that if you use `toString()` on a function and it shows [native code] that that was because it is native code. Like the output of `XMLHttpRequest.toString()` in firebug gives me:

```
function XMLHttpRequest()
{
    [native code]
}
```

When opening the [google keywords page](https://adwords.google.com/o/KeywordTool) and opening firebug console the following command: `$.toString()` gives me:

```
 function ()
   {
        [native code]
    }
```

I do wonder how they did that, maybe their $ object implements a `toString()` method returning that string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Firebug console, `$` is a pseudo-shortcut for `document.getElementById()` and that shortcut is implemented in Firebug's code.

Try typing `$("#doc")` in Firebug in that [google keywords page](https://adwords.google.com/o/KeywordTool).  You don't get a jQuery object, you get a DOM object from that page.

Comment: I get it now, the $ is available on every page unless it's got jQuery then the $ would refer to jQuery. Thank you for your answer. It's strange I never noticed the $ in other pages but now that I checked it's always there.